# zencoder bucket policy is not working with domain level privacy bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

when i try to add a zencoder bucket policy with domain level bucket policy it doesnt work. but when i just add zencoder bucket policy it does work. zencoder is throwing the error . Write access to 's3+us-west-1://zencoder123/hls-low/hls-low.m3u8' was denied. If this is a S3 URL, you may need to grant read access to Zencoder and try again. Get more information in the documentation.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ZencoderBucketPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1295042087538",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newuploads12/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1295042087538",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::395540211253:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newuploads12"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::newuploads12/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://www.vlogmo.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why error msg has `zencoder123` and bucket has `newuploads12`? Seems as totally different buckets.

Comment: @Marcin good eye . i changed the bucket name and forgot to add the new bucket name to zc.Job.create . thanks for your help everything is working like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **wrong bucket name**. The error message says `zencoder123` and the bucket policy has `newuploads12`.